# Working with modules inside codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the wiredesigns moduler extentions framework with codeigniter and I'm trying to find out what I need to do to get my links working correctly because the pages I"m trying to load are not loading. I'm receiving a error message saying "The page you requested was not found".

```
-application/controllers/dashboard.php
-application/modules/bios/controllers/quotes
```

When I'm inside the dashboard controller it shows the dashboard view file and there is a link that I want to open the quotes controller inside the bios module because it'll show the quotes view page so what is the correct I have this for the link:

```
link url/modules/bios/quotes
```

Is that not how the link is supposed to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the settings have been manipulated, the url should look something like this

```
url/<module name>/<controller name>/<method name>
```